# How to develop a counter on Flask with python

Tags: python, flask, counter

A friend asked me to develop a counter on Flask with python that updates itself when someone enters a number in an input but I'm a real beginner.

My method was to create a text file that keeps the precedent count so I could print the count + the input.

But I have a 400 error : "Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Below is the code I wrote so far

Thanks for your help!

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    choice = ''
    choice = int(request.form["choice"])

    if request.method == "POST":
        with open( "count.txt", "r" ) as f:
            count = f.read()
            output = """#Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n
            <html>
            <center>
            <p>The count is now : {count}</p>
            </center>
            </html>
            """.format(count=count)

            count = int(count)
            with open( "count.txt", "w" ) as f:
                f.write(str(count+choice) )
            print(output)
    else:
        choice = input("Enter a number : ")
        choice = int(choice)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I see you are not returning anything (`template` or `JSON`) for both `GET` and `POST` request. When are you getting this error? Are you able to submit the input?

Comment: No I can't submit the input. I used a portion of a previous webapp that required an input to extract word from a text to write the GET and POST methods but perhaps is it not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

To simplify you could just:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

counter = 1 #or whatever you want to start with

@app.route('/')
def main():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return str(counter)
```

So this code works - now you need to adapt the changes of yours to the file.

Btw for what do you need to store it in a .txt file?

Comment: Thanks DoakCode. Actually, I want to add the number entered by the user in an input. I thought that the counter would reinitiate every time if I declared the counter as counter = 0